# Why is JFXPanel giving focus to TextField

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-8, jfxpanel

The following code produces a `JFrame` containing a `JFXPanel` and a `JPanel`. Each of the panels contains a text field.

```
JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();

JPanel swingPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
swingPanel.add(new JTextField("Swing"));

JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
contentPanel.add(fxPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
contentPanel.add(swingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main Frame");
frame.setContentPane(contentPanel);

FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
root.getChildren().add(new TextField("FX"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root);

Platform.runLater(() -> fxPanel.setScene(scene));
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> frame.setVisible(true));
```

Suppose we start with the Swing text field focused. Then suppose I click inside the `JFXPanel` (but not within the bounds of its text field). The `JFXPanel` gives focus to the `TextField`.

Why does this happen? Why does the JFXPanel not keep its own focus? Why does it give it to the text field? How does it choose which of its components to give focus to? What is the correct way to prevent it giving its focus to the text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the `Scene` of the `JFXPanel` and more closely its [focusOwnerProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#focusOwnerProperty--).

When the `Scene` is created, it gives the focus to the `Node` stored in this property.

This is because of the `TextField` is the only `Node` in the scene-graph, which is [focus traversable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusTraversableProperty):

> Specifies whether this Node should be a part of focus traversal cycle.
>   When this property is true focus can be moved to this Node and from
>   this Node using regular focus traversal keys. On a desktop such keys
>   are usually TAB for moving focus forward and SHIFT+TAB for moving
>   focus backward. **When a Scene is created, the system gives focus to a
>   Node whose focusTraversable variable is true and that is eligible to
>   receive the focus, unless the focus had been set explicitly via a call
>   to requestFocus().**

As a solution you can add the following

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    root.setOnMouseClicked(e -> root.requestFocus());
});
```

This will focus the `FlowPane` on click.

Comment: So, calling `root.setFocusTraversable(true);` will result in the behavior the OP wants?

Comment: @James_D, seems unfortunately not.

Comment: So is the focus traversable explanation false, or else what is wrong with this approach?

Comment: The explanation is not false. If you set the focusTraversable property of the `TextField` to false, it does not become focused by default. I guess the key is in the "and that is eligible to receive the focus" part of the documentation.